# lists in python, with references

Tags: python, list, reference, copy

How do I copy the contents of a list and not just a reference to the list in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use a slice notation.**

`newlist = oldlist`

This will assign a second name to the same list

`newlist = oldlist[:]`

This will duplicate each element of oldlist into a complete new list called newlist

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#module-copy), and notice the difference between shallow and deep copies:

> The difference between **shallow and deep copying** is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A **shallow copy** constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A **deep copy** constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: Note that it's only relevant for containers of mutable data. A list of tuples containing integers gets no benefit from copy.deepcopy while a list with another list in it does.

Answer (score 5):

in addition to the slice notation mentioned by Lizard,

you can use `list()`

```
newlist = list(oldlist)
```

or copy

```
import copy
newlist = copy.copy(oldlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answes by Lizard and gnibbler are correct, though I'd like to add that all these ways give a shallow copy, i.e.:

```
l = [[]]
l2 = l[:] // or list(l) or copy.copy(l)
l2[0].append(1)
assert l[0] == [1]
```

For a deep copy, you need copy.deepcopy().